# in the github enterprise UI, is there a way to see commit statuses outside of the PR context?

Tags: github-enterprise

As part of our CI plans, dev branch commits will have statuses applied to them based on build/unit testing/etc.  Once a PR is opened to merge the dev branch to the product branch, those statuses will be visible and can be used as part of branch protection for the product branch.  However, is there anywhere in the UI where you can look at a particular commit directly, and view the statuses, or is it only through the lens of the PR?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The green check mark/red x icons representing the overall status of the checks also shows up in the basic commits list page in the GHE UI:

`https://<github url>/<owner>/<repo>/commits/<branch>`